# Custom normalization of Histogram

Tags: probability-or-statistics, data, dataset, histograms

Let us consider the following lists

```
SeedRandom[1]

list1 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 1000];
list2 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 200];
Histogram[{list1, list2}, 100]
```

The histogram is the following

[image]

I would like to generate a histogram for `list1` and normalize each bin by the sum of the counts of `list1`and `list2`.
So, for example, if in the bin 0 there are 7 points of `list1`and 2 points of `list2`, I would like the bin 0 of the new histogram to have the value 7/(7+2).

How can I do this?

Comment: If you're ending up with very many 0 divided by 0 bins, then what you're proposing sounds like a bad idea.  Maybe you could elaborate on why you want to normalize each bin by the sum of the counts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first precompute a histogram heights for both lists with `HistogramList`, then use this data as an input to a custom *hspec* function of `Histogram` (3rd argument).

If there are no elements in a bin, an error message (`Power::infy`) is thrown. Depending on your personal code aesthetics, you can either appropriately filter out these values *or* simply turn off the messagey with `Quiet`, which will also automatically make those bins disappear.

```
SeedRandom[1];
list1 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 100];
list2 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 20];

bspec = {-10, 10, 20/60};

totalcounts = Total@(Last@HistogramList[#, bspec] & /@ {list1, list2});

Histogram[{list1, list2}, bspec, Quiet[#2/totalcounts] &, ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

[image: Histogram]

Comment: In my real dataset there are bins where there is no statistics. How can i avoid the 1/0 error?

Comment: @apt45, please see my update.

Answer (score 2):

For each bin the ratio of the counts for `list1` to the total counts of `list1` and `list2` has a great deal of sampling variability with the extreme case of having some bins with the ratio of 0 over 0.

If the true probability densities (`pdf1` and `pdf1` were known, then maybe what corresponds to that ratio is `n1*pdf1/(n1*pdf1 + n2*pdf2)`.  In other words you need to state if you had the true pdfs, what would be the summary statistics of interest.  What is of interest should be definable in terms of the parameters of the distributions rather than something constructed solely from the sample data.

```
(* Take random samples from 2 distributions *)
SeedRandom[1234]
n1 = 1000;
n2 = 200;
list1 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, n1];
list2 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, n2];
```

So the first step is to construct an estimate of the two pdf's.  The "Bounded" option is used because I'm assuming you really know that the only positive probability density is between -10 and 10.

```
skd1 = SmoothKernelDistribution[list1, Automatic, {"Bounded", {-10, 10}, "Gaussian"}];
skd2 = SmoothKernelDistribution[list2, Automatic, {"Bounded", {-10, 10}, "Gaussian"}];
```

Now construct an estimate of the desired function of the true parameters.

```
Plot[{n1 PDF[skd1, z]/(n1 PDF[skd1, z] + n2 PDF[skd2, z])}, {z, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image: Function of parameters of interest]

In short, in the 21st century (and even in the late 20th century)
you should probably drop the construction of histograms and move on
to nonparametric density estimates (and associated functions).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach: Post-process `Histogram` output to modify rectangle coordinates as desired:

```
ClearAll[yMAX, postProcess]
yMAX = GroupBy[Cases[#, _Rectangle, All], #[[1, 1]]&, Max[{#[[-1]], #2[[-1]]}& @@@ #]&]&

postProcess = ReplaceAll[#, 
        Rectangle[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, c___] :> 
          Rectangle[{x1, y1 / yMAX[#][x1]}, {x2, y2 / yMAX[#][x1]}, c]] &;
```

Using Domen's example data:

```
SeedRandom[1];
list1 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 100];
list2 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 20];

bspec = {-10, 10, 20/60};

hist = Histogram[{list1, list2}, bspec, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
postProcess @  hist
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can do the post-processing *inside* `Histogram[...]` using the option `DisplayFunction -> (postProcess @ # &)`:

```
Histogram[{list1, list2}, bspec, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
  ImageSize -> Large, DisplayFunction -> (postProcess @ # &)]
```

> same picture

An example with more than two data sets:

```
postProcess @ Histogram[{list1, list2, list1, list1, list2, list1},
   bspec, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]